# RDP on Vmware workstation 15

Tags: virtual

Sorry for the newbie question.

I just installed Vmare workstation and created a windows server 2012 virtual machine(Set up remote desktop on the server 2012)

The virtual machine is hosted on the below Ip.
[image]

The virtual machine Ip.

[image]

Adapter settings

[image]

Nat Settings

[image]

When remote desktop from 192.168.2.120(virtual machine host) to 192.168.88.128 the remote desktop work fine , but when trying from a different PC on the same network(192.168.2.107) to remote desktop to (192.168.88.128) then remote desktop can be access.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your case is the **adapter option** you are using in VMWare for your Windows  Server. Rather than using a NAT adapter use the **Bridged** option.

Your answer ends above but if you need a bit insight of your problem then you can read the further part. The NAT IP of Windows server which is the guest machine (192.168.88.128) is reachable from the host machine(192.168.2.120) just because your host machine is internally connected (via a virtual switch) to the guest machine. If you check the network adapters in your host machine then you will find an adapter which will have an IP (192.168.88.1). Your host machine is communicating with your guest machine via this adapter.

The NAT option hides your virtual machine from the physical network. If you want to reach your machine then you have to configure some routing table entries to route packets (heading towards your VM) to your host machine and then again in your host machine you have to write a static route so that the packet received on 192.168.2.120 is forwarded to 192.168.88.0/24

Comment: Hi , did try the bridged option but can't rdp from the host machine as well as from pc on network , i did setup the nat settings

Comment: Alright then, check whether you are able to ping the two devices, so that we can be sure that they are able to communicate. Then, check firewall settings on both the ends, RDP uses both TCP and UDP port 3389. This ports should be open on both the ends, i.e., your Windows server and the other PC from where you are trying to take remote session of your VM.